# GCP: Disable Private Google Access for Serverless VPC access connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, static-ip-address

I'm trying to disable Private Google Access, which I can achieve on a subnet, but not for a Serverless VPC access connector. Alternatively if it's possible to disable the private access on the cloud NAT that I believe would also work. Are there any options for either of these?

The reason being, I require a request from a cloud function to use a static ip for whitelist purposes. This is working correctly for non-Google services, however GCP services are not recognising the ip, presumably because Private Google Access is routing the traffic internally on the GCP network.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible. Mainly because Google says and says again: don't trust the network.

And the correct pattern is to use IAM authorization to reach private function.

The problem will be for your external calls. The best way again, is to use IAM, with a service account and a service account key file deployed on the non Google environment. However, all the system aren't compliant with this. So, You can imagine something like this

```
External environment --> Cloud Function IP Check --IAM--> Private Cloud Function
                                                             ^
                                                             |
Google environment ----------------------IAM------------------
```

You can use a function to check the IP and then to call privately (with its own service account credential) the private function; like a proxy.

**Other solution**

If you really want to use only IP for authentication, even if it's not recommended, I think you can achieve this with a [serverless NEG on HTTP Global Load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts).

The HTTP Global load Balancer is a proxy and the HTTPS connexion is terminated at the Load balancer level. So, the [originator IP can be found in the header](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#x-forwarded-for_header)

```
External environment --> Global Load Balancer with pubic IP--> Cloud Function
                                      ^
                                      |
                                Public internet
                                      |
Google Environment --> NAT/VPC Connector
```

IMO, it's a lot of things to set up to reduce the security level. It solves your problem, but it's bad!